# make: mk-build-deps: commande not found

Tags: debian, make, debian-jessie, build

I followed the following tutorial to [build sage on debian](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianScience/Sage). When I run "debian/rules build-dep reset" inside the sage directory that I cloned from git, I get the following output:

```
mk-build-deps
make: mk-build-deps: commande introuvable
debian/rules:149: recipe for target 'build-dep' failed
make: *** [build-dep] Error 127
```

I have debian 8.0 (jessie). I have already installed build-essential and make. In French, "commande introuvable" means "nowhere to be found". I guess in English, it would be "command not found", wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mk-build-deps` command is a part of `devscripts`  package , to install it run:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```